# All elements of nsarray are present in nsstring or not

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I want to scan NSString (case insensitive) to check whether all elements of an array contain in that String or not ?

Eg.

```
    NSString *string1 = @"Java is pass by value : lets see how?";
    NSString *string2 = @"Java is OOP Language";

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Java",@"Pass",@"value", nil];
```

In this case string1 pass the test as it contain all keyword from array (i.e. Java,Pass,Value).

So, how can i achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't test it for speed, and it will fail on case-sensitive strings, but here's another solution (just in case)

```
NSArray *components = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSSet *textSet = [NSSet setWithArray:components];
NSSet *keywordsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
BOOL result = [keywordsSet isSubsetOfSet:textSet];
```

Keep in mind that `componentsSeparatedByString` will tokenize very silly, like "how?" instead of "how" you need.

Comment: This would fail if an element of the array would contain spaces. If that is not an issue: good idea! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL containsAll = YES;
for (NSString *test in array) {
    if ([string1 rangeOfString:test].location == NSNotFound) {
        containsAll = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```